# How to stop Registry reflection using C / C++ in Windows

Tags: c, windows, registry

I want to print the Values under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run**.

But instead of displaying those values, it redirects me to
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run** 
and prints out values under the Wow6432Node key instead.

I tried using RegDisableReflectionKey() but that does not stop the reflection of the subkeys.

```
hKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
lpSubKey = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
RegDisableReflectionKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
status = RegOpenKeyExW(hKey, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
status = RegQueryInfoKey(hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,  
&valueCount, &maxNameLength, &maxValueLength, NULL, NULL);

if (status == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{
    DWORD type = 0;
    DWORD index = 0;
    std::vector<wchar_t> valueName = std::vector<wchar_t> 
    (maxNameLength + 1);                                                                                                
        std::vector<BYTE> dataBuffer = std::vector<BYTE>(maxValueLength); 
    for (index = 0; index < valueCount; index++) 
{
        DWORD charCountValueName = static_cast<DWORD>(valueName.size());
        DWORD charBytesData = static_cast<DWORD>(dataBuffer.size());
        status = RegEnumValueW(hKey, index, valueName.data(),
 &charCountValueName, NULL, &type, dataBuffer.data(), &charBytesData);

if (type == REG_SZ) 
{
const auto reg_string = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(dataBuffer.data());  
printf("\nType: REG_SZ\n");
printf("\tName: ");
printf("%ls\n",valueName.data());
printf("\tData : %ls\n", reg_string);
}
```

The output displays values under
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Comment: Why not compile your application as a 64-bit? This will solve the issue for sure.

Comment: In the inconveniently omitted code commented as *"Registry key opened"* did you include the samDesired option of `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`, which a 64-bit application will ignore, but a 32-bit application will force to the primary registry and not the wow6432node reflection location? Just curious.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have included the code snippet which was previously commented.

Comment: @RaisaArief And did you try what I suggested ?

Comment: @WhozCraig The problem has been fixed now. Thank you for your help.