# Is it possible to redirect registry access from a 32bit application to the 64bit Registry without modifying the executable?

Tags: c++, redirect, registry, 32bit-64bit

I have a legacy application (C++, 32Bit) with no code that writes to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

This works fine in 32Bit environments. But in a 64Bit environment, all calls are redirected to this registry key instead, which is a default behaviour and makes sense in most cases:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

However, in this case, I do not get the desired behaviour from that application, because I definitely need to write to the 64Bit registry instead of the Wow6432Node. If I had the code for that application, I know I could alter that behaviour, but is there any way to force a 32Bit executable to redirect all registry-accesses to the 64Bit registry instead by setting some flags or similar mechanisms?

Thanks for any suggestions or ideas.

Comment: What's it doing writing to such a sensitive key?

Comment: It is possible but not for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` see [RegDisableReflectionKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry) _"...Applications should disable reflection only for the registry keys that they create and __not attempt to disable reflection for the predefined keys such as HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE__ ..."_

Comment: You might be able to patch the binary, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397336/how-to-stop-registry-reflection-using-c-c-in-windows) for inspiration.